# it's possible to use a variable as a property?

Tags: jquery

i have a JSON file with some information like the id of a DOM element (textfield or drop down box) and the way how to get the value like val(), text().

```
{
"textfield":"text()",
"textfield":"val()"
}
```

I use an ajax function to get the json data... this part is ok.

what I'am traying to do is to use the json objects as propertys

```
$.each(jsonData, function(key, getValue){
   console.log($('#myTextfieldID').getValue);
   });
```

or

```
$.each(jsonData, function(key, val){
   console.log($('#myTextfieldID')[getValue]);
   });
```

but the returned value is allways "undefined"

for shure I can do like this.

```
switch (getValue)
    {
    case 'text()':
        console.log($('#myTextfieldID').text());
    break;
    case 'val()':
        console.log($('#myTextfieldID').val());
    break;
    }
```

some one has an idea? Thx for help

Comment: object can't have 2 properties with same key. Assume this is an over simplification issue but pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because functions are referenced through variables into javascript objects, you can go like:

```
{
    "textfield":"text",
    "textfield":"val"
}
```

And :

```
$.each(jsonData, function(key, val){
   console.log($('#myTextfieldID')[getValue]());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all - if there is jQuery object returned - it doesn't have the property "text()", that is why you are getting "undefined".

Methonds in JavaScript are just object properties with type of Function.

So in your case you should store the name of the property

```
jsonData = {
    "textfield":"text",
    "textfield":"val",
    "textfield":"fooBar"
};
```

and then call that property if it is a 'Function' or return its value otherwise

```
$.each(jsonData, function(key, getValue){
   var d = $('#myTextfieldID')[getValue];
   console.log(d instanceof Function ? d() : d);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

get it, whats about attr with variables? like ...

```
{
    "textfield":"text",
    "textfield":"val",
    "textfield":"attr, myAttr",
}
```

and ...

```
$.each(jsonData, function(key, val){
   var parts = val.split(",");
   console.log($('#myTextfieldID')[parts[0]](parts[1]));
});
```

... but this is just working for the special case "myAttr", for the others I get "jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]".
Way I can not add some empty variables to this function?

this way is working ...

```
$.each(jsonData, function(key, val){
   var parts = val.split(",");
   if (parts.length > 1)
      console.log($('#myTextfieldID')[parts[0]](parts[1]));
   else
      console.log($('#myTextfieldID')[parts[0]]());
});
```

some html example

```
<input type="text" name="appName" value="myApp1" id="appNameID1" />
<input type="text" name="appName" value="myApp2" id="appNameID2" />
<input type="text" name="appName" value="myApp3" id="appNameID3" myAttr="someVal"/>
```